# Const method getting called on render in functional component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-functional-component

```
const App = props=> {
  const handleAdition=(abc)=>{
    console.log('called');
   props.dispatch({
     'type':'create',
     'payload':abc
   });
 }
  return (
    <div className="App">
    <AddB handleAdition={handleAdition}/>
    </div>
  );
}

const AddB=props=> {
  let [name, setName] = useState('');
  return (
    <div className="header">
      <div className="form">
      <label for='name'>Name</label>
      <input onChange={e=>setName(e.target.value)}type='text' name='name'/>
      </div>
      <button onClick={props.handleAdition({name})}> Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the method gets called infinitely until the stack is full. and the program fails.  I am new to functional components. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without `<AddB />` component's code the picture is incomplete

Comment: added it, it's actually called once, the props.dispatch rerending the component, this goes on for cycles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

`<button onClick={props.handleAdition({name})}> Add</button>`  to

`<button onClick={() => props.handleAdition({name})}> Add</button>`....

This is happening because onClick expects a function...